# osx metal doesn't render

Tags: swift, macos, 3d, metal

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77488/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-getting-started), extrapolating from iOS to OS X and everything compiles just fine, except I don't get anything rendered (even the clear color) without any errors. Could anyone please take a look and tell me what am I doing wrong here? I couldn't test this out on iOS like in the tutorial because iOS Simulator doesn't support Metal yet.

I have a custom view for Metal Rendering.
I'm not adding a sublayer (like in the tutorial) because the layer is **nil**. I suppose I need to *activate* it somehow and I don't know how.

```
import Cocoa
import Metal
import QuartzCore

class MetalView: NSView {

    var device: MTLDevice!
    var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    var renderPassDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor!
    var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer!

    var drawable: CAMetalDrawable {
        return (layer as! CAMetalLayer).nextDrawable()!
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // Device
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

        // Layer
        let metalLayer = CAMetalLayer()
        metalLayer.device = device
        metalLayer.pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm
        metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true
        metalLayer.frame = frame
        layer = metalLayer

        // Pipeline State
        let defaultLibrary = device.newDefaultLibrary()
        let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary!.newFunctionWithName("basic_fragment")
        let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary!.newFunctionWithName("basic_vertex")

        let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
        pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
        pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm

        do
        {
            try pipelineState = device.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor(pipelineStateDescriptor)

        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Failed to create pipeline state, error \(error)")
        }

        // Command Queue
        commandQueue = device.newCommandQueue()

        // Render Pass Descriptor
        renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .Clear
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

        // Vertex Buffer
        let vertexData:[Float] = [
             0.0,  1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
             1.0, -1.0, 0.0
        ]
        vertexBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(vertexData, length: vertexData.count * sizeofValue(vertexData[0]), options: MTLResourceOptions())
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
        let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)
        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3, instanceCount: 1)
        renderEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

}
```

And I have the following shader code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct VertexIn
{
    packed_float3 position;
};

vertex float4 basic_vertex(
    const device VertexIn* vertex_array [[ buffer(0) ]],
    unsigned int vertex_id [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    return float4(vertex_array[vertex_id].position, 1.0);
}

fragment half4 basic_fragment()
{
    return half4(1.0);
}
```

Comment: for `OS X` you could just make `MetalView` a subclass of `MTKView` and it's actually very easy if you look at my `Metal` tutorials on the http://mhorga.org blog.

Comment: I actually did that. I have a working example with MTKView, I just wanted to try to get it to work without it. Thanks for the link, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly setting the view's `layer` property is necessary but not sufficient for creating a so-called *layer-hosting view*. You can read about the distinction between layer hosting and layer backing [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html).

You almost certainly want a *layer-backed* view. To do this, override the `makeBackingLayer` method, in which you will create and configure your Metal layer and then return it. Then, early in your view's lifecycle (ideally in its initializer(s)), set the `wantsLayer` property to `YES`. This should be sufficient for getting your layer on the screen.

Comment: All of this is true, and it's also a sign that unless you're doing something with `CAMetalLayer` that you can't do with `MTKView`, you're better off with the latter.

Comment: @warrenm Thank you very much! That really helped. I read the article you mentioned and it turns out all I had to do is enable the CA layer for the view in my storyboard. I played around with the code and it turns out that I didn't have to override any methods and simply adding a sublayer to the now existing layer is sufficient.

Comment: Right; toggling that checkbox is enough to make the view layer-backed. I should've mentioned that, but wanted to give you a solution that would work beyond IB.

Comment: Thanks for the drive-by downvote. If this answer isn't working for you, please add a comment or ask a new question.